# composition and invertibility of 2-morphisms in a quasi-category

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I have two very basic and concrete question about composition and invertibility of 2-morphisms in quasi-categories (which are a specific model for $(\infty, 1)$-categories).

Let $C$ be a quasi-category, so it's a simplicial set (which I view as a sequence of sets $C_0, C_1, \ldots$ with various face and degeneracy maps) where the inner horns can be filled. My understanding is that what are called 2-morphisms are the elements of $C_2$.

1. What is the definition of a composition of two 2-morphisms (or a reference for where this is precisely stated)?

I'm not sure which 2-morphisms are composable. I just realized the following is probably wrong because I am trying to compose a 2-morphism from $0 \to 3$ with a 2-morphism from $2 \to 3$.

If $\sigma_1$ is a 2-simplex of $C$  $\sigma_1:0 \to 1 \to 3$ and $\sigma_2:1 \to 2 \to 3$ is another 2-simplex (I'm being slopping and writing $0, 1, 2$ instead of $w, x, y$ to denote $0$-simplices or objects in the hope it will make the horn filling easier to follow) then my guess to compute/define their composition as follows:
horn fill $0 \to 1 \to 2$ to a 2-simplex $\sigma_3$
now we have enough to fill the horn $\Lambda_1^3$ to get the 2-simplex $\sigma_4:0 \to 2 \to 3$ and this is an answer for a composition of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Is this correct?

[image]

2. In an $(\infty, 1)$ category, the $n>1$ morphisms are invertible (up to higher morphism). So given a 2-morphism $\sigma_1:0 \to 1 \to 3$ representing intuitively $h\sim g \circ f$ how do we use horn filling to find the inverse? What does being invertible even mean - I'm guessing that there is a 2-simplex $\sigma_2$ such that "composing" $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ as above we get a something homotopic to $id \circ h \sim h$? I actually don't understand what it means for a 2-morphism to be invertible.
   I guess each object or zero simplex gives rise to a degenerate n-simplex, and this is an identity $n$-morphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Composability" and "invertibility" are not, as you've noted, really the relevant primitive notions in a quasicategory. But horn-filling accounts for all the possibilities you want. The way to make this all make sense is to consider your quasicategory as generalizing the nerve of a 2-category. Given a 2-category $\mathcal K$, its nerve has $0$-simplices the objects of $\mathcal K$ and 1-simplices the 1-morphisms; a 2-simplex with boundary
\begin{array}{ccc}
x&\xrightarrow{f}&y\\&\searrow \scriptsize{h}&\downarrow \scriptsize g\\&&z
\end{array}
is a 2-morphism $\alpha:g\circ f\to h$. Higher simplices then arise from pasting diagrams in $\mathcal K$, much as for the nerve of an ordinary category. Thus the 2-simplices in a quasicategory aren't quite what you think of when you picture a 2-morphism; if $f$ is an identity, though, then such a 2-simplex corresponds precisely to a 2-morphism $g\to h$.

With this perspective, the construction you suggest does indeed capture the notion of composition of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Specifically, if the edges $0\to 1$ and $1\to 2$ are degenerate, then choosing the doubly degenerate 2-simplex for the $0\to 1\to 2$ face defines a composite $\sigma_1\circ \sigma_2$ that agrees with the composite in the 2-category $\mathcal K$ in case your quasicategory is the nerve of $\mathcal K$.

As for invertibility, we can tell a similar story. Given $\sigma_1$ with, again, $0\to 1$ degenerate, one can construct an "inverse" by filling a horn with $\sigma_1$ as the $0\to 1\to 3$ face, the $0\to 1\to 2$ face double degenerate, and the $0\to 2\to 3$ face degenerate on the nondegenerate edge of $\sigma_1$. Again, in case your quasicategory is the nerve of the 2-category $\mathcal K$, this reconstructs the inverse of the 2-morphism represented by $\sigma_1$.

Your construction gives a good generalization of composition to 2-morphisms, but in fact the most natural notion of composition of 2-morphisms in a quasicategory is to compose together any *three* 2-morphisms that fit together into an outer horn. That is, there's no good reason, from the perspective of the quasicategory, to focus on filling horns where the $0\to 1\to 2$ face is degenerate.

On the other hand, to talk about invertibility in a quasicategory it really helps to make some edges degenerate. If we picture a 2-simplex as a 2-morphism $(g,f)\to h$, then it doesn't make sense to ask for an inverse $h\to (g,f)$. A quasicategorical way of stating formally that a quasicategory "is" an $(\infty,1)$-category is, then, that "every special outer horn has a filler", where an outer horn is special if its $0\to 1$ edge (in the case of a 0-horn) or its $n-1\to n$ edge (in the case of an $n$-horn) is an equivalence (which means it might as well be degenerate.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informative answer, and correcting my confusions about 2-simplices verses 2-morphisms. Also I wasn't aware quasi-categories satisfied an special outer horn filling condition, but your answer helped me find an argument that uses only inner horn fillers

Comment: @usr0192 Yes, the argument you gave works fine as long as you're happy to focus just on those partially degenerate simplices. The special outer horn thing is only relevant when you want to understand more general 2-simplices.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kevin Arlin's answer here is my revised understanding (decided to post as an answer because not enough space for a comment)

For composition fill, in the $\Lambda^3_1$-horn
[image]

and for inverse here is an argument using just filling inner horns:
[image]

Comment: How can I show that $\sigma$ really has a two-sided inverse? I found the solution with special outer horn extension property.